# Ubuntu 17.04 HDMI loses connection after login

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, amd-graphics

My TV is connected to my computer via HDMI.

Ubuntu 17.04, unity

ATI Radeon HD 8350 
The video card driver is "Radeon" which is the default with 17.04.

LG TV

It used to work correctly until 2 weeks go. I don't know what has changed but my tv now shows "no signal".

Tried to disconnect the HDMI cable and reconnect it many times (it used to solve the no signal problem before). Tried also different HDMI ports.

**When I switch off the computer and start it again with the TV on, Ubuntu starts on the TV and I see the login screen. But after I login, the connection is lost and the TV shows "no signal".**

On the computer,
when coming back from sleep mode, the screen sometimes flicker until I minimize the open window and open it again.
So it might be a video card driver issue !?

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

My TV started connecting correctly without any modifications.

My second computer screen just died few days ago and I disconnected it. 
Now when opening the TV, it connects correctly. 
So it's probably a problem with the 2 screens and a TV. 
I will update when my new second screen arrives.

**UPDATE:**

When the second screen arrived and I connected it, the TV connection was lost again.
So I checked the solution suggested by JM and the TV does appear now in the Ubuntu setting, and it is off (: 
Switched it on and everything is working again.
Thanks JM.

Thanks (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experiencing a similar issue on 17.04 with an external LG monitor. As soon as I logged in, my LG monitor would display "No Signal" and enter a power-save mode.

What I found was that the monitor identifier had changed within the Displays setting. Unsure as to why, but the monitor, which used to display a detailed identifier (something along the lines of "LG ... 34""), had reverted to using a generic identifier ("GSM 34"") and was set to "OFF".  I fixed the issue by enabling that external display within the display settings menu.

Comment: Thanks J M. The TV does not appear in the display setting for me.